# Pass generator with json (preferably over MQTT)

Tags: python, json, object, generator

Is it possible to send functions or generators with json protocol?

What I tried:

```
import json
import pickle

def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

pickled=  pickle.dumps(gen)
jsoned = json.dumps(pickled)


enjsoned = json.loads(jsoned)
enpickled = pickle.loads(enjsoned)

>>> for i in enpickled():
        print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

>>> print(pickled, type(pickled))
('c__main__\ngen\np0\n.', <type 'str'>)
>>> print(jsoned,type(jsoned))
('"c__main__\\ngen\\np0\\n."', <type 'str'>)
>>> print(enjsoned,type(enjsoned))
(u'c__main__\ngen\np0\n.', <type 'unicode'>)
```

From the code, it is obvious I had an idea to pickled it send it over json and enpickled it somewhere else.

This works inside script. But for sure I cant send it, because as you can see, the encoding is in string. So if I send it for example over MQTT, I would be just sending some reference in string.

Any idea if it is possible to send over json functions or generators?

Also I would like to note I dont want to use EVAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little searching I found possible way

```
import dill

def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

import dill
dilled_gen = dill.dumps(gen)

with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(dilled_gen )

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    gen_byted  = f.read()
gen_reloaded = dill.loads(gen_byted)

>>> for  i in gen_reloaded():
        i


0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Dilled generator is in bytes:

```
>>> dilled_gen 
'\x80\x02cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x00K\x01K\x02KcU x\x19\x00t\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00D]\x0b\x00}\x00\x00|\x00\x00V\x01q\r\x00Wd\x00\x00Sq\x05NK\n\x86q\x06U\x05rangeq\x07\x85q\x08U\x01iq\t\x85q\nU5C:\\Users\\marti\\Desktop\\Stackoverflow\\dumpGenerator.pyq\x0bU\x03genq\x0cK\x04U\x04\x00\x01\x13\x01q\r))tq\x0eRq\x0fc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0cNN}q\x10tq\x11Rq\x12.'
```